# Says laptop battery is 100% but its not completely

Tags: system, hardware, power, battery

Hi the wingpanel indicator says the battery is 100% charged. When i click on to the battery statistics it shows that it is just shy of being full but is no longer charging and is labeled as charged.
  Its energy shows 23.5 Wh of 23.7 Wh. I know its just barely shy but i have seen it charge to full before. Anyone know whats going on or how to fix this?

Here is a screen shot. [image: battery Screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calibrating the battery may help with this. To calibrate it you just need to fully charge it, then use it and discharge completely and charge it again til 100%.
If you still experience the same issue then is probably what cheekyngeeky pointed out.

Comment: It seems to have fix it by draining it completely then recharging it.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of laptops(like mine) have a BIOS configuration which sends the information as charging done when the battery has charged >=98 %. In Windows there are specific chipset drivers which correct this disparity to indicate exact values(as of Windows 7 they have to be installed). However, in Linux, they are often shown to be charged. So that is not an issue. AFAIK, this small error has been corrected in newer versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, and is being tracked and worked on:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/1315434

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt seem to be sorted on ELementary os Loki latest my battery shuts the pc down at around 60% doesnt matter if its been charged to 100%. On restart (it wont start without cable plugged in when battery flat) the battery shows 60% so something is amiss.
[edit] by allowing the battery to flatten on BIOS boot screen to shutdown state, seems to have reset the battery/calibrated as Elementary is now showing 0% on turn on yea!. Later...by inserting charger it upsets calibrate level so I reset again and then did a full charge to 100%. Unfortunately, the indicator does not seem to follow terminal call results eg it will read 80% when terminal results give 40% (or similar) terminal call: 
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=7400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=7696000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=7854000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=35952000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=34573000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=14168000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=40